# Is there a way to programmatically change am to pm in a TimePickerDialog?

Tags: android, datetimepicker, timepicker

I'm looking for a way to dynamically change the AM/PM within a TimePickerDialog for my Android application while using 12 hour format. I'm hoping to toggle the AM to PM and visa versa when the hour changes from 11 to 12 within the dialog but before the user clicks th set button. Is this possible or will I need to look into creating a custom TimePickerDialog control? My current code is below. Thanks for the help!

```
    // Start Time
    starttime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.starttime); 

    starttime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            boolean is24HourFormat = use24HourFormat();
            new TimePickerDialog(DutyHoursForm.this, 
                    startTimeListener, 
                    startDateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
                    startDateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
                    is24HourFormat).show(); 
            } 
    }); 

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener startTimeListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() { 
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) { 
        startDateAndTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay); 
        startDateAndTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute); 
        updateStartTime(); 
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialise a variable to keep track of the hour before the change - like lastCurrentHour
then you can do this in onTimeChanged:

```
public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    if(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this)) return;

    if(lastCurrentHour == 0 && view.getCurrentHour()==11 ){
        view.setCurrentHour(23);
    }else

    if(lastCurrentHour == 11 && view.getCurrentHour()==0 ){
        view.setCurrentHour(12);
    }else

    if(lastCurrentHour == 12 && view.getCurrentHour()==23 ){
        view.setCurrentHour(11);
    }else

    if(lastCurrentHour == 23 && view.getCurrentHour()==12 ){
        view.setCurrentHour(0);
    }
    lastCurrentHour = view.getCurrentHour();
}
```

Find a working example [here](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.franzkrauth.meetingbuddy).